# Network Bridge using Wireless Adapter Windows 7

Tags: adapter, wireless, bridge

It's normal that netsh bridge show adapter doesn't give me any results? I am using my wireless adapter of personal laptop. Maybe its normal, its because my adapter don't allow promiscuous mode?

How can I check if my wireless interface allows promiscuous mode?
Thanks ;)

Answer (score 3):

With **netsh bridge show adapter** you can show only already bridged adapters not **bridgeable** adapters. Current Microsoft Windows Operating Systems (Windows 7, Windows 8) only allow creating bridge adapter and adding adapters to bridge in GUI mode.

The command **netsh bridge install** for example is not supported. There is even no **netsh bridge add** or **netsh bridge remove** command at all.

If you want a command line based tool take a look at [Network Bridging Utility](https://sourceforge.net/projects/networkbridgingutility/)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.intel.com/support/network/sb/CS-004185.htm

Yes, all currently marketed Intel® PRO/100, Intel® PRO/1000, Intel® Gigabit, Intel® PRO/10 Gigabit, and Intel® 10 Gigabit adapters support Promiscuous mode. A network management agent or other software (such as "Network sniffer") is required to tell the OS to turn on the promiscuous mode support. Users cannot enable or disable the support.